# Code snippet button doesn't edit the current code snippet

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I can create and insert a snippet, but I can't seem to edit existing snippets. When I click the "Code snippet" button, the code editor pops up blank:

1. edit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424477/responsive-sortable-list-supporting-drag-drop-for-bootstrap/27221306#27221306)
2. position the caret into the code snippet
3. click the code snippet toolbar icon.

The editor will come up blank.

Thanks to animuson, I noticed the "edit the above snippet" under the preview. This was below the fold and I thought that clicking the *Code snippet* toolbar icon would edit the code snippet.

Answer (score 7):

In the preview of the post, below the big black "Run code snippet" button, there is a link that says "edit the above snippet" - this will open the snippet in the edit box. You can make changes and click the Insert Into Post button again, and it will replace the existing snippet with the new, modified one.

Comment: Ah... I have completely missed that. Not a bug but a UX enhancement then?

Comment: They're open to suggestions on how to improve that UI. The only thing I could imagine is detecting if the text cursor is inside a block of text that represents a snippet and grabbing it. *shrugs* Not sure how viable of an option that is.

Comment: @animuson I actually just tried that myself, expecting it to work. Came here after it didn't.

Comment: It is telling that in my attempt to remember how to do this that I came here today - scroll scroll scroll to/through the code and look for that link at the bottom, seems like a peer to "Run Snippet" to me.