# Should the snippet edit link be more conspicuous?

Tags: feature-request, editing-help

I often revise new user posts to either add a snippet demo or fix them. When I mention this in a comment to prevent confusion I want to refer to the snippet edit link, but it's in a terribly bad position. It's not just outside the edit box, it's *below* the snippet preview. If the snippet is long, the link is *way* down the screen. Unfamiliar users often miss it and attempt to revise the snippet markdown directly, which tends to result in calamity, frustration, and throwing-in of the effort towel.

And I get tired of thinking how to write something like, "click the [whatever it's labeled exactly--I forgot again] link under the snippet in edit mode" in a way that's not cumbersome to me *and* them.

The snippet edit link needs to be more conspicuous and in a better location. Maybe it should be integrated into the editor toolbar. Maybe it should be available when *not* in edit mode. At any rate... the whole UX surrounding snippet edits badly needs improvement.

See also [a related question from 7 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280052/code-snippet-button-doesnt-edit-the-current-code-snippet) that gets at the same issue.

[image]

Comment: Totally agree. It should be a button on the snippet; [Run code snippet] [Copy snippet to answer] [Edit snippet]. Show it whenever, just make it appear, prominently, inside the snippet UI.

Comment: That would be a good start, but it would still be below the fold in many cases (and therefore missed by oblivious new users). If the Edit button could be at the top....

Comment: Yeah. On the other hand, UX-wise, when you're reading the question, more often than not, you want to dig directly into the code... Maybe in edit mode, bring all the buttons to the top? As long as I can say "next to the Run code snippet button" I'm good. If they can't find a big blue button, there's no helping them (and I am painfully aware of how many people include snippets of code that do nothing when that button is clicked).